# Можно ли задать таймеру на яваскрипт интервал в одну неделю? Чтобы через неделю запускался заново.

Tags: javascript

Есть таймер обратного отсчёта: http://jsfiddle.net/victorpavloff/92tuq/
Можно ли задать интервал в одну неделю? Чтобы по окончании недели он опять начинал отсчитывать 7 дней?

Comment: Теоретически можно, а в чём проблема? Практически -- как вы заставите юзера неделю не закрывать ваш сайт?

Comment: Никак не заставлю. Хотелось бы узнать практически, как это сделать. Чтобы например юзер зашел сегодня, у него 5 дней. Зашел завтра, у него 4 дня.

Comment: Храниет дату захода (или от чего вы там хотели неделю отсчитывать) в cookies. При каждом заходе на страницу вытаскивайте значение и проверяйте.

Comment: Возможно вы захотите реализовать то что написал fori1ton с помощью jQuery 

http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_cookie

Comment: Куки не нужны. Таймер должен обновляться не через неделю после первого моего захода. А в каждый понедельник.

Comment: Тогда 

http://javascript.ru/Date

и

http://javascript.ru/Date/getDay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значит так, если правильно понял, то Вы хотите по окончании недели запустить таймер заново? Тут без PHP+MySQL(или любой базы) не обойтись. Реализация такова: Человек зашел на страницу, в бд записало timestamp когда он зашел, далее просто при перезагрузке страницы из БД берется timestamp и запускается js скрипт на "анимацию" данного таймера. И если timestamp, когда он зашел, больше чем timestamp+[1неделя], то обнуляем таймер и перезаписываем timestamp который записался изначально. Удачи)

Comment: Конечно, можно и в файл. Если у вас не большое число пользователей.  Человек зашел на сайт, берем значение из функции time() (PHP) и записываем в файл строку с пользователем и значением. А при открытии заново сайта ищем строку в файле с пользователем, и берем значение времени. Выставляем в js, запускаем "анимацию" таймера.

Comment: Я не знаю, правильно ли я выразился. Но таймер должен перезапускаться не через неделю после захода человека на сайт, а тупо через неделю. Например в каждый понедельник. Тут вряд ли нужно запоминать, когда человек зашёл на сайт.

Comment: Тогда в чём вообще проблема? Найти количество дней между текущей датой и ближайшим понедельником?

Comment: Тогда как вы говорите, тупо записываем time() в файл, при открытии заново сайта, берем из файла время $time, сравниваем 

if(time() > $time+604800) {
 // перезапись даты в файл, выполнение действий.
}

Comment: Извините, но я писать за Вас это не буду. Читайте о PHP.

Comment: Наверное if(time() > $time+604800)  не подходит. Допустим, я зайду на сайт сегодня, в файл количество секунд по time() запишется. Но, прикинем, что следующий человек зайдёт на сайт через 9 дней. Тогда счётчик будет уже не до понедельника, а до среды считать. Или нет?

Comment: Нужно как-то реализовать, чтобы в 00:00 воскресенья в файл записывалась time(), наверное.

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Файл не нужен. Сегодня, допустим, вторник -- значит, прошло два дня с прошлого воскресенья.

Comment: Почему файлы не нужны? А где тогда хранить дату? Или вы имеете ввиду определять день недели яваскриптом? Я не особо понимаю в яваскрипт, поэтому пытаюсь использовать существующий скрипт. Сейчас делаю следующее: в предложенном мной скрипре на место даты я из файла вывожу дату, записанную в файле. А в файл дата записывается следующим образом: скрипт запускается кроном в 00:00 в воскресенье, определяется дата и плюсуется 7 дней. Инфа записывается в файл.